Catia Macro " Collapse all geometrical sets "
I would like to know if there is any macro that can collapse all geometrical sets.
I have a macro that can create multiple geometrical sets, but unfortunately in expanded way . that means every time should collapse manually .
thank you in advance

oCATIA.StartCommand("Collapse All") will close all the containers in your tree.

@ C R johnson's code , working good
Sub CATMain()
    ' Check if CATIA is running
    If CATIA Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "CATIA is not running."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Try to collapse all
    On Error Resume Next
    CATIA.StartCommand ("Collapse All")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed to execute command: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

